# How to send a Visual Studio 2010 solution to someone made up of several projects (in several directories)

Tags: visual-studio-2010

Quite a simple one I think, but hopefully someone can help out.

I have a project in My Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects called EvalServiceLibrary. I build this into a project and then added it as a DLL to a web site, in My Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects.

So my solution as a whole contains two projects. The dll project and the web site which contains the DLL. This solution I guess holds the paths of those two projects.

What I want is to be able to send the entire solution to someone without it complaining about not being able to find various paths and whatever. I'm not sure what the best way to do this is.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right that the solution contains the paths to your projects. You could edit your solution file in Notepad to change these paths.

Normally when you create a solution file the projects have the parent folder so you can use relative paths. What you could do is remove EvalServiceLibrary from your Web Project solution, then move the EvalServiceLibrary to a child folder of your Web Project solution and then readd it the project file to the solution.

Then you should have a relative path so you could ZIP the whole folder and send that to your colleague.